# Jasper Reports - Out of Memory errors

Tags: report

I see the below error and then Out of memory errors while trying to create a report. The version of jasper used is 3.0.0. Could some one please help me understand what is happening here?

> at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)  at
>   sun.font.FontLineMetrics.clone(FontLineMetrics.java:101)  at
>   java.awt.Font.defaultLineMetrics(Font.java:2115)  at
>   java.awt.Font.getLineMetrics(Font.java:2127)  at
>   sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.getLogicalBounds(StandardGlyphVector.java:376)
>     at
>   sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createLogicalBounds(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:220)
>     at
>   sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getAdvance(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:129)
>     at java.awt.font.TextLine.init(TextLine.java:275)   at
>   java.awt.font.TextLine.(TextLine.java:121)  at
>   java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.makeTextLineOnRange(TextMeasurer.java:473)
>     at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.getLayout(TextMeasurer.java:605)  at
>   java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:438)
>     at
>   java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:406)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderNextLine(TextMeasurer.java:505)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:338)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:291)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:987)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.prepare(JRFillTextField.java:528)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:344)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:346)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:305)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1382)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:692)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:275)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:117)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:879)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:801)

Answer (score 2):

I see a few errors regarding *font*, *drow lines*, *line break*, ecc. Try to create a report without layout because you can exclude this kind of errors and Jasper Reports don't notify to you in compile phase. So your error could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have exceeded from boundry of jasper report page. I too got same exceptions. Generally do not delete "Bands" from report. Just lessen their height.